# Cant read from SQL Server database in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am currently working on a college assignment in which I am having trouble reading data from a SQL Server database. I'm attempting to read the `Dentist Name` column and then add these names to a combobox.

However when I input the column name it shows an error.

My table is called `dentistInfo` with columns `Dentist ID`, `Dentist Name`, `Dentist Surname`, `DOB` and `Gender`.

Eventually when I get to the reading done correctly I will then hopefully be able to populate their details when the names are selected from the combobox.

```
public partial class Dentist_Info : Form
{
    Surgery mySurgery = new Surgery();
    private SqlConnection conn;
    private SqlCommand cmd;
    private SqlDataAdapter da;
    Surgery _formsSurgery;

    public Dentist_Info(Surgery SurgeryToDisplay)
    {
        _formsSurgery = SurgeryToDisplay;
    }

    public void FillCombo()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = GGJG; Initial Catalog = DentistDB; Integrated Security = True");
        SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT *  FROM DentistInfo", conn);

        SqlDataReader myreader;
        conn.Open();

        try
        {
            myreader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (myreader.Read())
            {
                string dname = myreader.GetString("Dentist Name");
                comboBox1.Items.Add(dname);
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: change this line `string dname = myreader.GetString("Dentist Name");` to 
`string dname = (string)myreader["Dentist Name"];` sure would help if we knew what the error was as well.

Comment: you have spaces as part of your column names and this will raise an error when evaluating SQL query. If your database is SQL Server, try this "SELECT [Dentist ID], [Dentist Name], [Dentist Surname], DOB, Gender FROM DentistInfo". If it is MySQL then use grave accent instead of sqare brackets.

Comment: You need to post the actual error message. It's like going to the garage and saying my 'car is broken, fix it'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: I recommend you putting [] in the Dentist Name since it has a space between the two words, which might cause you the error, or change the name from the Database to DentistName

```
public void FillCombo()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = GGJG; Initial Catalog = DentistDB; Integrated Security = True");
        SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT *  FROM DentistInfo", conn);
        conn.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectCommand);
        da.fill(ds);

        foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["[Dentist Name]"].ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

As per addition instead of using conn.Open() and conn.Close(), as the answer of the first user you can surround the connection inside a using like so:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = GGJG; Initial Catalog = DentistDB; Integrated Security = True"))
{
   //your codes here no need for conn.Open() and conn.Close()
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for the answers...

I have input the code JC Borlagdan put up however I have been given the following error: Argument 1: cannot convert from System.Data.SqlClient.SqlComand to string.

it is underlined on this bit of code: DataSet ds = new DataSet(SelectCommand); 

The SelectCommand within the brackets is underlined.

Comment: Brilliant thanks JC - The names have populated to the combobox - Many Thanks for all your help.

Comment: glad to help, happy coding!

Comment: And by the way, in retrieving data from SQL, it's faster/efficient to use DataRow than using DataTable

Answer (score 1):

Pro-tip: If you want to ask about an error, *post the error*.

In any case, the problem is easy to spot in this case. There's no overload of `GetString` that accepts a string as an argument - you can only use the column index.

So either you need to pass the column index (`myreader.GetOrdinal("Dentist Name")`) or you need to use the indexer (`(string)myreader["Dentist Name"]`). In either case, make sure to handle possible NULL values properly - data reader simply throws an exception if you try to read an SQL NULL value.

As an aside, your `try`...`catch` can be simplified (and more useful):

- When you want to rethrow an exception, use `throw;` (no "argument"). Wrap the exception only if you have some information to add.
- The `catch` clause isn't required. It seems that you're only using it for the `finally` - it's perfectly fine to just use `try`...`finally` without the `catch`.
- `conn` can never be `null` in the finally clause - your `try` isn't long enough.
- For a pattern like this, you want to use `using` instead of `try`...`finally` anyway. You should also use `using` for the data reader.

Comment: A data reader can read a null fine so long as you read to something that can handle nulls.  Read to an object, check if it's a string and cast if it is.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Which is known as "handling possible NULL values properly". `GetString` (and friends) will throw, the indexer will return `DBNull.Value`. The easiest (and cheapest) way is to just use the `IsDBNull` method.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies..I will ensure to enclose the error on any further problems..I'm going to try the answers given when I get home.. Just so I understand, Is the error happening when it hits a null value and I didn't have an exception for this

Comment: @Griff No, you're getting a compiler error, not an exception - there's no overload of `GetString` that takes column name as an argument.